# ESXi 4.1 licensing

Tags: vmware-esxi, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have a server running ESXi 4.1 with an expired evaluation license. I tried to register a free license with VMware, but all I managed to obtain is a free ESXi 5.0 license. However, I can't seem to be able to apply an ESXi 5.0 license to an ESXi 4.1 server.

I was wondering if it possible still possible to get a free license for ESXi 4.1?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question, it's more concerning VMWare's free licence offerings.

Comment: @Alex: Since only VMWare can really help the OP, it's a duplicate of said question.

Comment: What duplicate question are you guys referring to? Is it the generic one that is intended to kill all licensing questions?

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely, usually previous versions are only supported by the manufacturer for licence holders. Unfortunately I beleive you'll have to upgrade to esxi 5. There is an article here http://www.ivobeerens.nl/2011/08/18/upgrading-to-vmware-esxi-5/ on how to update to esxi 5 using both the update manager and an interactive install. If I were you I would back up the config on the server and back up the datastores to other disk if it's stored locally, however it should upgrade fine.